# Text of select column in jqgrid is not exporting to excel

Tags: jqgrid, export-to-excel, free-jqgrid

The demo Link - "https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ovq05x0c/6/" uses the code

```js
.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
    caption: "",
    title: "Export to Excel(.XLSX)",
    onClickButton: function () {
      var filename = "jqGrid.xlsx",
            data = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "lastSelectedData"), i, item,
          dataAsArray = [["Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total",
                          "Closed", "Shipped via"]];

          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            item = data[i];
            dataAsArray.push([
                item.name,
              new Date(item.invdate),
                item.amount, item.tax, item.total,
              item.closed, item.ship_via]);
          }

          var ws_name = "SheetJS";
          var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new(),
              ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(dataAsArray);
          XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, ws_name);
          XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename);
        }
  });
```

in this demo- click on export button export value of jqgrid select formatter column instead of text of formatter select column(Shipped via). And my requirement is text should export in excel. Can anyone help to solve this issue.

Comment: Since this is a custom export - see the code for export - you will need to manually put the text. I recommend you to switch to a supported commercial version  of jqGrid - [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) where this problem is solved and you do not need to write any additional code.

Comment: Hi Tony,  thanks for your recommendation. I have read Trirand .net webforms controls  related links. I have some questions and specific requiremens ,I wlll send  you mail  @   sales@trirand.net  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can fix the code by calling `formatter` function and removing `<span class='ui-jqgrid-cell-wrapper'>...</span>` wrapper in case of usage `autoResizable: true` property. The modified code could looks like

```js
.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
    caption: "",
    title: "Export to Excel(.XLSX)",
    onClickButton: function () {
      var filename = "jqGrid.xlsx",
          self = this,
          data = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "lastSelectedData"), i, item,
          iColByName = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "iColByName"),
          dataAsArray = [["Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Closed", "Shipped via"]];

      function getFormattedValue (item, cmName) {
        var value = self.formatter(item.id, item[cmName], iColByName[cmName], item, "add", item),
            ex = /^<span class='ui-jqgrid-cell-wrapper'>([^<]+?)<\/span>$/i.exec(value);

        return Array.isArray(ex) && ex.length === 2 ? ex[1] :value;
      }

      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        item = data[i];
        dataAsArray.push([
          item.name,
          getFormattedValue(item, "invdate"),
          getFormattedValue(item, "amount"),
          getFormattedValue(item, "tax"),
          getFormattedValue(item, "total"),
          item.closed,
          getFormattedValue(item, "ship_via")]);
      }

      var ws_name = "SheetJS";
      var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new(),
          ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(dataAsArray);
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, ws_name);
      XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename);
    }
});
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/mpyuxto9/14/